# DbLinq "char" special character

Tags: postgresql, char, dblinq

I used the DbMetal tool to generate a class for my database. It worked, but then I added some "char" types to the database. Now when I try to generate the class I get the error

```
DbMetal : Don't know how to convert the SQL type '"char"' into a managed type. Parameter name : dataType
```

Has anyone encountered this? Is there a workaround or an alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, be careful of the difference between the `char` data type and the `"char"` data type in PostgreSQL. They are not the same, and `"char"` is normally just used for columns in system tables.  Secondly, neither one is a very good choice for most application data; consider `varchar` or `text` instead. Do these work in dblinq?  Maybe they were just trying to steer you away from bad choices.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean `"char"` which is a special Postgres type for the storage of a single byte of information?  Or did you mean `char(n)` or `varchar(n)`?

In general, outside of some rare cases, `varchar()` and `text` are far preferred.  Unless you quote `"char"` it assumes you mean the standard SQL `char` type.  This is not one of the more self-documenting decisions in PostgreSQL....

It would not surprise me if `"char"` is poorly supported.  If you really need to use it (or even if not) it would be worth filing a bug report with nogsql if this is still happening.  As a workaround use a standard type mile `char(1)`.